std::function<__callback void (void)> vs std::function<void (void)>?

std::function<__callback void (void)>
std::function<void (void)>
Please tell me about the difference between these two.

__callback appears to be the keyword provided by WDK.
I think it's different from the function calling protocol I knew.
Do you also use it to use functions in normal user-level applications?
Is it a kind of user-friendly keyword that separately defines asynchronous functions?
What is the difference between 1 and 2 above, and when should I use number 1?

The latter is standard library provided and should be used when writing user level program.

This is unimportant. std::function works in such way that adding this __callback can be only harmful. Template parameter is used to get convenient way to build internal templates. Calling convention do not have impact on this template.

Also provide the source. Just asking about random identifiers that may or may not be applicable from one implementation to other is not clear. Also don't worry about implementation details. Use the things(for the most part) provided by the standard library.

@user12002570 I don't think the duplicates answers OPs question. OP mentions the WDK and that it's in there that __callback is used. From Advanced Annotations: "__callback - The function can be used as a function pointer.". That doesn't say much but presumably means something to the compiler.

I agree with Ted Lyngmo and have reopened this.

For passing function pointers accross the user/kernel mode boundary? I'm just guessing.

__callback or __Callback ?

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Good catch. It's __callback. :-)

It's merely an annotation from Microsoft's SAL (source-code annotation language).
From Advanced Annotations: "__callback - The function can be used as a function pointer". It is defined as:
#define __callback __allowed(on_function)

It doesn't do anything to the function signature, but is an allowed annotation on functions, so unless you are SAL-annotating your own code already, don't use __callback either.
